# Почему при запуске сервера на Flask возникает ошибка 502 Bad Gateway?

Tags: python, nginx, flask

На ubuntu установлен сервер Flask с nginx, supervisor, gunicorn. Все работает. Хочу связать Flask c базой данных Mysql. Установил Mysql на ubuntu, создал базу данных MyDB. Сервер Mysql работает.
Вот `app.py`:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
app = Flask(__name__)

mysql = MySQL()

app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'MyDB'

mysql.init_app(app)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
 if request.method == "POST":
        details = request.form
        firstName = details['fname']
        lastName = details['lname']
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO MyUsers(firstName, lastName) VALUES (%s, %s)", (firstName, lastName))
        mysql.connection.commit()
        cur.close()
        return 'success'
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

`/var/log/nginx/error.log` выдает ошибку:

```
2024/03/23 09:19:31 [crit] 24699#24699: *7 connect() to unix:/var/www/project_flask/ipc.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.31.1, server: flask.cubinez.ru, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/var/www/project_flask/ipc.sock:/", host: "flask.cubinez.ru"
```

То есть не создает файл `ipc.sock` в рабочей директории `/var/www/project_flask`
Пробовал сам создать, права менял - не помогает.
Вот конфиги супервизора и nginx:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение!
Проблема была в установке модуля flask_mysqldb.

1. Нужно установить модуль в виртуальной среде проекта:
   `source myprojectenv/bin/activate` и `pip install flask_mysqldb`
2. Если не установится модуль flask_mysqldb, тогда придется устанавливать библиотеки:
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76875507/can-not-install-apache-airflow-providers-mysql-pkg-config-error